# Number of Spots in a Spatial Seurat object

Tags: rna-seq, transcriptome

I have got an integrated seurat object of 21 Spatial samples. I want to know how many spots are in all the samples together, Is there a way I can do that? Also, Please suggest any R Packages that do good ploting with spatial data (Like dittoSeq for Single cell).
Thanks a lot,
AMK